# Segmentation fault when try to get the 'current_execute_data' on a PHP extension

Tags: php, c, php-extension

I'm trying to develop a php extension for print all functions call like a backtrace. But when I'm trying to get the current function a segmentation fault is throw. What is the problem with my code?

My php test code:

```
function a() {
    b();
}

function b() {
    c();
}

function c() {
    var_dump(hello_world());
}

a();
```

My extension code:

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include "config.h"
#endif

#include "php.h"
#include "php_ini.h"
#include "ext/standard/info.h"
#include "php_hello_world.h"

PHP_FUNCTION(hello_world)
{
    zend_execute_data *ptr  = NULL;
    ptr = EG(current_execute_data); // <----- Segmentation fault (core dumped)
}

const zend_function_entry hello_world_functions[] = {
    PHP_FE(hello_world, NULL)
    PHP_FE_END
};

zend_module_entry hello_world_module_entry = {
    STANDARD_MODULE_HEADER,
    "hello_world",
    hello_world_functions,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,   
    NULL,   
    NULL,
    PHP_hello_world_VERSION,
    STANDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES
};

#ifdef COMPILE_DL_hello_world
#ifdef ZTS
ZEND_TSRMLS_CACHE_DEFINE()
#endif
ZEND_GET_MODULE(hello_world)
#endif
```

Comment: when I compile the php without the flag '--enable-maintainer-zts' this code works ... there is something else needed to do when this flag is enabled to access the globals varaibles?